# Autocomplete on a dynamic view in android

Tags: android, dynamic, autocomplete

I've created a form for the user to add to my database.  Part of my form can have a varied number of fields so I've created a button to add my custom layout with the fields.

```
View child = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.ingredient_input, ll, false);
ll.addView(child);
```

That works great so far.

For each view that I add there is an AutoCompleteTextView that will access the same list.  I can get the one I already have on the page to work using:

```
acIng1 = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.acIng1);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                    NewRecipeActivity.this, 
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                    nameList
                    );
acIng1.setAdapter(adapter1);
```

but I cannot get autocomplete in any of the views I add dynamically because I don't have their ids.  Any ideas on how to run autocomplete on these new fields?  Here's my custom view:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="number" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<AutoCompleteTextView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:ems="10" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvIng1Unit"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Unit" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Is that layout R.layout.ingredient_input. I mean the XML you are showing?

Comment: @Jawad Le Wywadi Yes it is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add an id to your layout(the one you add programatically):

```
<AutoCompleteTextView
...android:id="@+id/auto"
/>
```

and use findViewById on your child View, the view that you created.

```
View child = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.ingredient_input, ll, false);
ll.addView(child);
child.findViewById(R.id.auto);
```

Don't worry the ids will not be mixed up. Since you are always searching in a different view even if it is the same id.

Comment: I tried adding an id but it still only did autocomplete on the first field.  Also the child refers to the LinearLayout so how would I get the AutocompleteTextVIew since it is inside of that?

Comment: Just use findViewById on you child view. You should ensure to use the findViewByid on the child with child.findViewById().

Answer (score 0):

Easy solution: find all `AutoCompleteTextView` in the container and set adapter.

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                    NewRecipeActivity.this, 
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                    nameList
      );//adapter

 ViewGroup v= (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.LinearLayout1);//container

 for(int i=0; i<((ViewGroup)v).getChildCount(); ++i) {
     View nextChild = ((ViewGroup)v).getChildAt(i);
     if (nextChild instanceof AutoCompleteTextView) {
         ((AutoCompleteTextView)nextChild).setAdapter(adapter1);
     }
 }
```